# OpenERP domain : char compare

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Here's is what i've tried to do:

```
<field name="of_num" domain="[('etat','=','Terminé')]"/>
```

where 'of_num' is a many2one field and 'etat' is a function field of char type.

But it seems not working.I still get all records in my dropdown list.

I have also tried with some other text with no unicode chars but still the same.

I tried also to use 'ilike' operator and tried to put domain in python code with the field definition but with no chance.

**EDITED**

I've figured out the source of my problem :
the field 'etat' is computed but not stored since I'am using 'store=false'.

it's working with store=True.
Still, I don't wan't to store it because my value needs to be computed every time a view is loaded.

Could anyone please help me to do that without having to store my value ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found to get around my problem is to use a Boolean field that is stored and updated every time my function is computed (of the function field 'etat').

Answer (score 0):

Use fnct_search. For functional fields there is an argument called 'fnct_search' which returns a search domain condition.
For example

```
_columns = {
'a':fields.float('A'),
'b':fields.float('B'),
'total_fn': fields.function(_total, fnct_search=_total_search, string='Total'),
}
def _total(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
       res[obj.id] = obj.a + obj.b
    return res

def _total_search(self, cursor, user, obj, name, args, domain=None, context=None):
    ids = set()
    for cond in args:
        amount = cond[2]
        cr.execute("select id from your_table having sum(a,b) %s %%s" % (cond[1]),(amount,))
        res_ids = set(id[0] for id in cr.fetchall())
        ids = ids and (ids & res_ids) or res_ids
    if ids:
        return [('id', 'in', tuple(ids))]
    return [('id', '=', '0')]
```

Here _total returns the value to display for the field total_fn, fnct_search returns the list of tuple need for searching. So whenever we are giving the argument [('total_fn','=',1500)]